# Prove that $\int f d\delta_x = f(x)$ where $f$ is a measurable non-negative function and $\delta_x$ is the point mass measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

**Context**: Given a simple function $s = \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\chi_{A_i}$ its Lebesgue integral is defined as $$\int s d\mu = \int \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\chi_{A_i}d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\mu(A_i).$$If $f$ is non-negative and measurable, then we can choose a non-negative nondecreasing sequence of simple functions such that $s_m \rightarrow f$ pointwise as $m \rightarrow \infty$. Then $$\int f d\mu = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\int s_m d\mu = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i,m}\mu(A_{i,m}).$$

**Exercise**: Suppose $\mu$ is the *point mass* at $x$, that is $\delta_x(A) =1$ if $x \in A$ an $0$ otherwise. Then we must prove that $\int f d\delta_x = f(x)$ where $f$ is a measurable non-negative function.

**Attempt**: Letting $(s_m)$ be the sequence that approaches $f$ at the infinity, then $$\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}s_m(x) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^nc_{i,m}\chi_{A_{i,m}}(x) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}c_{k,m} = f(x),$$for $x \in A_k$ (which we can assume to be only measurable set that contains $x$). Thus, $$\int f d\delta_x = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=1}^mc_{i,m}\delta_x(A_{i,m}) = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}c_{k,m} = f(x).$$

Comment: your solution is correct.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you.